# App Build Failed with an Exception in react native, A problem occur in evaluating script

Tags: node.js, react-native

i m new in react native.. when i was run my app following error occurred in command line. Kindly guide me with an appropriate solution... Thanks.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\My Final Year Project\Home_Page\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 170
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797    throw err;    ^Error: Cannot find module '@react-native-community/cli'Require stack:- E:\My Final Year Project\Home_Page\android[eval]    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)    at [eval]:1:13    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:20)    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:306:38)    at Object. ([eval]-wrapper:9:26)    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)    at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:80:25) {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: [ 'E:\My Final Year Project\Home_Page\android\[eval]' ]}
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running 'node -e console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);' command.
:ReactNative:Running 'node -e console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);' command failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read over the react-native getting started docs again. It seem like you missed a step. The error is saying you are missing `@react-native-community/cli` module which should have been added during your initial react-native environment set up.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bad release of v1.9.6, which was fixed in 1.9.7. Try updating it

OR i would suggest you to install yarn and then run

> yarn install

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with react-native 0.61.5 and cli version 1.0.9.

Updating @react-native-community/cli worked for me.

$ npm install @react-native-community/cli@4.0.1